# Polly Framework issue with C# Windows Based Application

Tags: c#, oracle, ftp, polly

I have a C# based Windows Based Application and using Visual Studio 2017

I am trying to execute from where the connection got dropped for connection to Oracle Database and FTP while the application is running..

I used the below code to check FTP as well as Oracle Connectivity at some location in the Application

```
var retryTimes = 100;
var retryableErrorCodes = new[] { "ORA-03113", "ORA-03114", "ORA-12543", "ORA-12170", "ORA-12154" };

RetryPolicy retryPolicyFTP = Policy
    .Handle<Xceed.Ftp.FtpInvalidStateException>().Or<Xceed.Ftp.FtpIOException>()
    .WaitAndRetry(retryTimes, _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

RetryPolicy retryPolicy = Policy
    .Handle<OracleException>(ex => retryableErrorCodes.Any(errorCode => ex.Message.Contains(errorCode)))
    .WaitAndRetry(retryTimes, _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

Policy.Wrap(retryPolicyFTP, retryPolicy).Execute(() =>
{
     ExecuteSomeFunction();
});
```

When I try every time by disconnecting the VPN, I mean connection to Oracle and FTP will be lost at this time and re-connect again and break the application, the execution point will be at only

```
Application.Run(MainForm.Instance);
```

Why it is not re-executing from the point it is dropped.

**EDIT**

I tried doing POC with Windows Application and after disconnecting the Oracle Connection, I am getting the below error.

[image: Windows App POC for Oracle Connectivity]

Please throw some light on this

Comment: Is an Exception type thrown that is _not_ handled by any of the Policies?

Comment: For a Console Application, it is working fine as a POC. Whatever exception is thrown is handled by Polly. I don't know what is going on here.

Comment: I'd suggest deepdiving into the Exception. Is it _really_ thrown from `ExecuteSomeFunction()` to start with? Maybe the Policy doesn't even apply at all?

Comment: That is a very large function and it continuously shows the status in the Grid in the FrontEnd. But it is getting stuck at `Application.Run` function highlighting in somewhat Green color.

Comment: @Fildor, I tried POC with Windows App and Oracle Connection, simple App and after disconnecting the Oracle Connection, I get the error as Exception Unhandled. Modified the Question. Please have a look at it.

Comment: @Ch. Is the error code of *Connection request timed out* included in the `retryableErrorCodes`?

Comment: I have added this condition to the `retryableErrorCodes` and it is starting again in POC Windows App. But need to check in the Main App. Thank you.

Comment: @Ch. Did you manage to check it?

Comment: Yeah it is working! Thanks for your support.

Comment: @Ch. I'm glad that it worked. Could you please leave a post where you detail the solution? You can accept that as the answer then.